# Which one is an "Event Handler" in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to ask a basic question about "event handler" in ReactJs.

Here's some sample of React component :

```
import React from 'react'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
  }

  render () {
    const { isDisabled = false } = this.props;
    return (
      <button onClick={() => isDisabled && this.handleClick()}>
        Hello Button
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

Does the "event handler" in that component is the "handleClick" function, or the `() => isDisabled && this.handleClick()`, or the "onClick" it self?

Thank you

Comment: There is no official definition of "event handler". An event handler is just a function that "handles an event". If you only want to give this name to the function you pass directly to `onClick`, then do that. But it also isn't too much of a stretch to refer to `handleClick` as an event handler, if that function contains most of the event processing logic. There aren't strict rules here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed to `onClick` is [the event handler](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

> With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.

Also, according to [Passing Arguments to Event Handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers), you can conclude that the `onClick` is an event handler.

> Inside a loop, it is common to want to pass an extra parameter to an event handler. For example, if id is the row ID, either of the following would work:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

Comment: I think in react, they will not pass you the event  `e` into that handler. I could be wrong though.

Comment: If “they” you mean react so the event passed as in normal html element

Comment: yes, I mean react lib, I had this couple weeks ago, angular is not passing the event for some reason. I dont quite understand how your second button click listender works. It looks kinda wrong to me as you invoke the .bind function directly. Is this a higher order fcuntion that returns the actual handler?

Comment: @TheFool: React does pass an event object to the handler. `.bind` returns a new function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: nice, TIL. I never have to use bind luckily but good to know. thanks.

Comment: Its not mine, its from the docs, in “modern” react you don’t bind functions anymore. You should post a new question, Ill gladly answer, I prefer not answering in comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a function definition (you assign an anonymous function to the variable `handleClick`)

```js
 handleClick = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
  }
```

Below will attach an anonymous function `() => {}`  as event handler to the button element which invokes your original `handleClick` function

```js
 <button onClick={() => isDisabled && this.handleClick()}>
```

The event name is "click" and the handler for it is what you assign to it. In this case, an anonymous function that invokes the `hanldeClick`, if `isDisabled` evaluates to false *(short circuit evaluation)*.

Normally they are called "event listeners" in javascript tough.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the function pass to the binding events like `onChange`, `onBlur`, `onClick` is event handler.

There are multiple ways to [handle events in React JS](https://www.cluemediator.com/handle-events-react)

1. Inline method binding
2. Bind method in constructor
3. Method binding using arrow function
4. Bind method parameters
5. Binding method with parameters using arrow function

Check the above reference site for more information.